# Measure of Intersection of Translate of Sets of Infinite Measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$ with $\mu(A)=\mu(B)=\infty$ and $\mu(A\cap B)=0$. Does there necessarily exist some $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for which $\mu(A\cap(B+x))=\infty$?

This seems likely as, if it did not hold, there would exist two sets of infinite measure so that the intersection of any translate has finite measure, which is admittedly counterintuitive, but not unthinkable... However, I'm not quite sure how to prove this.

Comment: Hi, I post an answer but I have a feeling that you were trying to ask a different question. Perhaps you want to prove that no such $x$ exists?

Comment: @Yanko Your answer is good but I indeed did not state the question correctly, will fix

Comment: I edited my answer and gave an example in which such $x$ exists as well

Comment: @Yanko I edited to add the density condition.

Comment: I read your edit, but it doesn't matter if it is dense because instead of $A$ and $B$ just look at $A\cup \mathbb{Q}$ and $B\cup \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Yanko Ah, yes. This is just a poor question then... Oh well, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take $A=(-\infty,0)$ and $B=(0,\infty)$. Then $B+x = (x,\infty)$ and $A\cap B+x = (x,0)$ if $x<0$ and empty otherwise. This set is always of measure $x<\infty$.

---

If instead you are looking for an example of $A$ and $B$ for which there exists such an $x$. Then take

$B=(0,\frac{1}{2})\cdot\mathbb{N}$ - all the numbers with fractional part smaller than half, $A=(\frac{1}{2},1)\cdot \mathbb{N}$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $B+x=A$ and $A\cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: What about on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: @RomainS it also works